Expressing the event $ \{ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n = l \}$
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{H}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables s.t. $\forall n \geq 1 \quad X_n$ is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable. Let $\omega \in \Omega$, $n \geq 1$, $L \in \mathbb{R}$.
I am trying to describe the event
\begin{equation*}
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n = L \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
In other words,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} X_n(\omega) = \\
\inf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{m \geq n} X_n(\omega)
\end{equation*}
The limit means that
\begin{equation*}
 \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists n \geq 1 \text{ s.t. } \sup_{m \geq n} X_n(\omega) \in (L -\varepsilon, L + \varepsilon) = (L - \varepsilon, \infty) \cap (- \infty, L + \varepsilon)
 \end{equation*}
Observe that
\begin{align*}
    & \sup_{m \geq n} X_m(\omega) > L - \varepsilon \iff \exists m \geq n \text{ s.t. } X_m(\omega) > L - \varepsilon \\
    & \sup_{m \geq n} X_m(\omega) < L + \varepsilon \iff \forall m \geq n \quad X_m(\omega) < L + \varepsilon 
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
    \sup_{m \geq n}X_m(\omega) \in (L - \varepsilon, L + \varepsilon) \iff \exists m \geq n \text{ s.t. } X_m(\omega) > L - \varepsilon \text{ and } \forall m \geq n \text{ } X_m(\omega) < L + \varepsilon
\end{equation*}
that is,
\begin{equation*}
    \omega \in \{ \sup_{m \geq n}X_m \in (L - \varepsilon, L + \varepsilon) \} \iff \omega \in \bigg( \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{X_m > L - \varepsilon\} \bigg) \bigcap \bigg( \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} \{ X_m < L + \varepsilon \} \bigg)
\end{equation*}
Now, keeping $\varepsilon$ fixed, I should introduce the $"\exists n  \geq 1 \text{ s.t.}"$ part. But simply adding a $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}$ before that event feels wrong intuitively, as it yields:
\begin{align}
  \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \Bigg( & \bigg( \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{X_m > L - \varepsilon\} \bigg) \bigcap \bigg( \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} \{ X_m < L + \varepsilon \} \bigg) \Bigg) = \\
  & \bigg( \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \{X_m > L - \varepsilon\} \bigg) \bigcap \bigg( 
   \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} \{ X_m < L + \varepsilon \} \bigg)
\end{align}
which I think doesn't make sense. I would rather write
\begin{equation}
    \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n \in (L - \varepsilon , L + \varepsilon) = \bigg( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=n}^{\infty} \{X_m > L - \varepsilon\} \bigg) \bigcap \bigg( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} \{ X_m < L + \varepsilon \} \bigg)
\end{equation}
but I wouldn't know how to make it consistent with the $"\exists n  \geq 1 \text{ s.t.}"$.
Finally, introducing the $"\exists \varepsilon > 0 \text{ s.t.}"$ part would involve (I'll substitute the $\varepsilon$ with a $\frac{1}{k}$ to keep the unions and intersections countable)
\begin{equation}
    \limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \Bigg( \bigg( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \{X_m > L - \frac{1}{k}\} \bigg) \bigcap \bigg(
   \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} \{ X_m < L + \frac{1}{k} \} \bigg) \Bigg)
\end{equation}
Is this correct? And if it is, how can it be consistent with the $"\exists n  \geq 1 \text{ s.t.}"$ part, given that once I am making unions over $n \geq 1$ but the other time I am making intersections over $n \geq 1$ ?
Any feedback would be appreciated
